# After adding enctype="multipart/form-data to my form and trying to submit, it goes to another page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 2 pages
The first is : admin.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_GET['page'])){
    $_GET['page'] = 'home';
}//end if
include_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/function.php");
?>

<?php include_once("header.php"); ?>
<?php include_once("menu.php"); ?>

<?php 
    switch ($_GET['page']) {
        case 'category_list':
            include_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/modules/category_list.php");
            break;
        case 'category_add_edit':
            include_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/modules/category_add_edit.php");
            break;
        case 'color_list':
            include_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/modules/color_list.php");
            break;
        case 'color_add_edit':
            include_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/modules/color_add_edit.php");
            break;
        case 'product_list':
            include_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/modules/product_list.php");
            break;
        case 'product_add_edit':
            include_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/modules/product_add_edit.php");
            break;
        case 'cart':
            include_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/modules/cart.php");
            break;
        case 'order':
            include_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/modules/order.php");
            break;
        default:
            include_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/modules/home.php");
            break;
    }
?>




<?php include_once("footer.php"); ?>
```

And the second one is: /modules/product_add_edit.php

```
<form action="<?=($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>?<?=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']?>" enctype="multipart/form-data method="POST">
```

When i try to submit and upload my image and input fields it goes to:
http://project6bootstrap4-v1/admin.php?id=&category_id=7&name=Anything&description=Anything&price=352&quantity=431&type=Anything&image=monitoracerCopy.jpg&color_id=8&add_category=

When it should go to: http://project6bootstrap4-v1/admin.php?page=product_add_edit
What i am doing wrong?

Comment: `enctype="multipart/form-data` is missing the closing quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quotes are missing for enctype attribute

```html
<form action="<?=($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>?<?=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```